# Javascript page redirect on Signup form submission

Tags: javascript, css

I'm very new to front-end development and I'm trying to write my first code on creating a Signup form.
**Requirement**

1. I want to create a simple Sign up form with Firstname, Lastname, and Password and a Signup and Cancel button.
2. The Signup button should take the form-data and display it on clicking
3. And the results page that displays the form-data should also have an 'Ok' button that takes it to another page.

**Problem Area**
I was able to successfully have a working code for steps 1 and 2:
So I have a simple CSS for the form with inputs for Firstname and LastName, Password, Signup and Cancel button and able to display the results like:
**Firstname Lastname, You are now Signed up**
but I'm stuck at step 3 as I cannot have a working 'Ok' button which would take me to another page.

I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me here.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<script>
  function formDisplay() {
    var first = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var last = document.getElementById("lname").value;
    var result = first + ' ' + last + ', ' + ' ' + "You are now Signed up ";
    document.getElementById('display').textContent = result;
    document.getElementById('open-button').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('ok').style.display = "block";

  }
  function openform() {
    document.getElementById("form-container").style.display = "block";
  }
  function closeDisplay() {
    document.getElementById("form-container").style.display = "none";
  }
  function redirect() {
    window.open("https://www.guru99.com/computer-programming-tutorial.html");

  }
</script>

<button class="open-button" id="open-button" onclick="openform()"><b>Learn Coding</b>
  <emoji>‍</emoji>
</button><br> <br>
<div id="form-container" class="form-container">
  <form id="display" class="display">
    <b>
      <h3>Signup</h3>
    </b>
    <b>Firstname: </b><input type="text" id="fname" name="" required />
    <br> <br>
    <b>Lastname :</b> <input type="text" id="lname" name="" required />
    <br> <br>
    <b>Password : </b><input type="password" name="" required />
    <br> <br>
    <button id="button" class="signup" onclick="formDisplay()">Signup</button>

    <button id="button" class="cancel" onclick="closeDisplay()">Cancel</button>

    <button id="ok" class="ok" onclick="redirect()">OK</button>
  </form>
</div>
<style>
  .form-container {
    color: black;
    opacity: 0.85;
    max-width: 350px;
    background: transparent;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #bfcdcf;
    padding: 20px;
    height: auto;
    align-content: center;
    position: relative;
    display: none;

  }

  .open-button {
    max-width: 350px;
    background-color: crimson;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid crimson;
    padding: 5px;
    height: auto;
    align-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .signup {
    background-color: rgb(1, 228, 1);
    padding: 5px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 10px;
    align-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .cancel {
    background-color: rgb(245, 10, 10);
    padding: 5px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 20px;
    align-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .display {
    color: black;
    align-content: center;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .ok {
    color: black;
    background-color: rgb(70, 130, 243);
    padding: 5px;
    align-content: center;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #bfcdcf;
    bottom: 500px;
    margin: 1 auto;
    left: 200px;
  }
</style>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you upload that code that is working and failing?

Comment: Hi Sarah, can you please share your code so i can get a look.

Answer (score 0):

When you replace the content of the form with your "result" you are actually removing the OK button from the DOM. A simple solution is to remove it from the form and also give it a type="button" also.

```html
<html>
<script>
  function formDisplay() {
    var first = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var last = document.getElementById("lname").value;
    var result = first + ' ' + last + ', ' + ' ' + "You are now Signed up ";
    document.getElementById('display').textContent = result;
    document.getElementById('open-button').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('ok-button').style.display = "block";

  }
  function openform() {
    document.getElementById("form-container").style.display = "block";
  }
  function closeDisplay() {
    document.getElementById("form-container").style.display = "none";
  }
  function redirect() {
    window.open("https://www.guru99.com/computer-programming-tutorial.html");

  }
</script>

<button class="open-button" id="open-button" onclick="openform()"><b>Learn Coding</b>
  <emoji>‍</emoji>
</button><br> <br>
<div id="form-container" class="form-container">
  <form id="display" class="display">
    <b>
      <h3>Signup</h3>
    </b>
    <b>Firstname: </b><input type="text" id="fname" name="" required />
    <br> <br>
    <b>Lastname :</b> <input type="text" id="lname" name="" required />
    <br> <br>
    <b>Password : </b><input type="password" name="" required />
    <br> <br>
    <button id="button" class="signup" onclick="formDisplay()">Signup</button>

    <button id="button" class="cancel" onclick="closeDisplay()">Cancel</button>

  </form>
    <button id="ok-button" type="button" class="ok" onclick="redirect()">OK</button>
</div>
<style>
  .form-container {
    color: black;
    opacity: 0.85;
    max-width: 350px;
    background: transparent;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #bfcdcf;
    padding: 20px;
    height: auto;
    align-content: center;
    position: relative;
    display: none;

  }

  .open-button {
    max-width: 350px;
    background-color: crimson;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid crimson;
    padding: 5px;
    height: auto;
    align-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .signup {
    background-color: rgb(1, 228, 1);
    padding: 5px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 10px;
    align-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .cancel {
    background-color: rgb(245, 10, 10);
    padding: 5px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 20px;
    align-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .display {
    color: black;
    align-content: center;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .ok {
    color: black;
    background-color: rgb(70, 130, 243);
    padding: 5px;
    align-content: center;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #bfcdcf;
    bottom: 500px;
    margin: 1 auto;
    left: 200px;
  }
</style>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, everyone. I guess when I tried putting the button outside of the form my original css was messing it up. I really appreciate everyone's inputs.

Answer (score 0):

In short, when you set the `textContent` property on form, you're removing the button. A simple solution to this would be to place the `ok` button outside of the form.

```html
<html>
  <script>
    function formDisplay() {
      var first = document.getElementById("fname").value;
      var last = document.getElementById("lname").value;
      var result = first + ' ' + last + ', ' + ' ' + "You are now Signed up ";
      document.getElementById('display').textContent = result;
      document.getElementById('open-button').style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('ok').style.display = "block";

    }

    function openform() {
      document.getElementById("form-container").style.display = "block";
    }

    function closeDisplay() {
      document.getElementById("form-container").style.display = "none";
    }

    function redirect() {
      window.open("https://www.guru99.com/computer-programming-tutorial.html");

    }

  </script>

  <button class="open-button" id="open-button" onclick="openform()"><b>Learn Coding</b>
    <emoji>‍</emoji>
  </button><br> <br>
  <div id="form-container" class="form-container">
    <form id="display" class="display">
      <b>
        <h3>Signup</h3>
      </b>
      <b>Firstname: </b><input type="text" id="fname" name="" required />
      <br> <br>
      <b>Lastname :</b> <input type="text" id="lname" name="" required />
      <br> <br>
      <b>Password : </b><input type="password" name="" required />
      <br> <br>
      <button id="button" class="signup" onclick="formDisplay()">Signup</button>

      <button id="button" class="cancel" onclick="closeDisplay()">Cancel</button>

    </form>
    <button id="ok" class="ok" onclick="redirect()">OK</button>
  </div>
  <style>
    .form-container {
      color: black;
      opacity: 0.85;
      max-width: 350px;
      background: transparent;
      background-color: whitesmoke;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #bfcdcf;
      padding: 20px;
      height: auto;
      align-content: center;
      position: relative;
      display: none;

    }

    .open-button {
      max-width: 350px;
      background-color: crimson;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 1px solid crimson;
      padding: 5px;
      height: auto;
      align-content: center;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .signup {
      background-color: rgb(1, 228, 1);
      padding: 5px;
      height: auto;
      margin: 10px;
      align-content: center;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .cancel {
      background-color: rgb(245, 10, 10);
      padding: 5px;
      height: auto;
      margin: 20px;
      align-content: center;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .display {
      color: black;
      align-content: center;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .ok {
      color: black;
      background-color: rgb(70, 130, 243);
      padding: 5px;
      align-content: center;
      display: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #bfcdcf;
      bottom: 500px;
      margin: 1 auto;
      left: 200px;
    }

  </style>

</html>
```